# Помогите восстановить нерабочую флешку на linux

Tags: linux

Был под виндой решил проверить битые сектора на флешке какой то неизвесной утилитой после сканирования флешка умерла. Я ейчас под Ubuntu нужно восстановить флешку. Gparted пишет "/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label" он её видит но только лейбел создать не может и разметить и отформатировать тоже не может. Пробовал через консольную fdisk тоже не помогло или я что то не так сделал. Помогите пожалуйста реанимировать флешку под linux. Форматрование через mkfs тоже не помогает. Искал в интернете как восстановить label на флешке но ничего из предложенного не помогло.

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 29,5 GiB, 31691112448 bytes, 61896704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: MXT-USB Storage Device (scsi)                                      
Disk /dev/sdb: 61896704s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, примите как факт, что ваши данные на флешке *уже* потеряны.

От рута:

`fdisk /dev/sdb` (но предварительно убедитесь, что она именно sdb, а то ещё второй винт себе перепилите).

Введите команду "p" и убедитесь, что количество места (байт/секторов) на устройстве соответствует вашей флешке. Если нет — заканчивайте процедуру.

Путём ввода команды "d" поудаляйте все имеющиеся разделы.

Командой "n" создайте новый primary раздел (начальный и конечный сектора оставьте по умолчанию.

Командой "w" запишите результаты (примечание: если вы случайно производили операции над неправильным диском, с этого момента ваши данные на нём потеряны. Вы предупреждены).

Выйдите из fdisk и посмотрите на результат: `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`. На нём теперь должен быть раздел sdb1 размером на весь диск.

Создайте на нём файловую систему: mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1

Comment: Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

Comment: Не помогло, есть еще какие то варианты?

Comment: @user1 а как именно не помогло? На каком этапе?

Comment: на этапе записи утилитой fdisk, делал все пошагово как описано и после того как нажал w что бы записать, выдало вот это Command (m for help): w The partition table has been altered. Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table. Syncing disks. Но флешка как была мертвая так и осталась

Comment: Почему не перешли к следующему этапу?

Comment: Да я создал файловую систему через mkfs она вроде создалась, Никаких ошибок выдано небыло но флешка по прежнему не определяется и gparted с ней тоже не может работать

Comment: Думаю, всё. Можно, конечно, поискать в городе понимающих железячников и проконсультироваться с ними, но оно того обычно не стоит.

Comment: Понятно, буду конечно пытатться еще что нибудь придумать но думаю флешку я окончательно убил). Спасибо вам что откликнулись и постарались помочь.